# How to speed up 1/2 hour to sort 133 new entries in 2,700 entry Bash Array in RAM?

Tags: arrays, bash, performance

I have an array of directory names and stats such as owner, modified date, file count, total file sizes, etc. When adding 133 new directory names to the bash array of about 2,700 existing directory names it takes about 1/2 hour to sort it. The time is unacceptable and how can it be improved (**NOTE:*** This is a self-answered question).

I've tried creating an *associative array* to speed up processing but it doesn't allow sequential reading of keys, just some random hash table unsorted order.

Here is the relevant code snippet:

```bash
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
BubbleSortDirsArr () {

cp ~/.bafmanDirs ~/.bafmanDirs~ #Make backup copy
IFS="|" read -ra DirsArr < ~/.bafmanDirs
DirsArrCnt=${#DirsArr[@]}
DirsArrUnsetCount=0

TotBump=0
Sorted=false
while [[ $Sorted == false ]]; do
  Sorted=true
  i=0               # TODO: Use HoldNdx to update progress
  LastNdx=0
  LastKey=""
  EOF=false   # fudge it


  while [[ $i -lt $DirsArrCnt ]] ; do
    DirsArr[$i]=false
    CurrNdx=$i
    CurrKey=$(echo "${DirsArr[$(( $i + 1 ))]}" | tr -dc '[:alnum:]/')

    if [[ "$CurrKey" > "$LastKey" ]] || [[ "$CurrKey" == "$LastKey" ]]; then
        LastNdx=$CurrNdx
        LastKey="$CurrKey"
        i=$(( $i + $OneDirArrCnt))
        continue
    fi

    HoldNdx=$(( $CurrNdx + $OneDirArrCnt )) # When done we'll restart here.
    if [[ $HoldNdx -ge $DirsArrCnt ]] ; then
        echo "%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Hold>Last OVERRIDE: "
        echo "HoldNdx: $HoldNdx CurrNdx: $CurrNdx LastNdx: $LastNdx"
        echo "CurrKey: $CurrKey"
        echo "LastKey: $LastKey"
        HoldNdx=$CurrNdx    # Curr= last array entry, restart at LastKey swapped
        EOF=true   # fudge it
    fi

    # If last index > curr index, we can't swap
    if [[ $LastNdx -gt $CurrNdx ]] ; then
        echo "ABORT!!!  LastNdx: $LastNdx greater than CurrNdx: $CurrNdx"
        echo "CurrKey: $CurrKey"
        echo "LastKey: $LastKey"
        exit
    fi

    Sorted=false    # Restart sort from array top later

    printf "= START ====================== Loop 3:"
    echo " HoldNdx: $HoldNdx CurrNdx: $CurrNdx LastNdx:   $LastNdx"
    echo " CurrKey: $CurrKey"
    echo " LastKey: $LastKey"

    Bump=0
    while [[ "$CurrKey" < "$LastKey" ]] || [[ "$CurrKey" == "$LastKey" ]] ; do

        Bump=$(( $Bump + 1 ))
        # Move Last entry to work array
        WorkArr=()
        j=$LastNdx
        for (( c=1; c<=$OneDirArrCnt; c++ )); do WorkArr+=("${DirsArr[j++]}"); done ;

        # Move current entry to last entry
        j=$LastNdx
        k=$CurrNdx
        for (( c=1; c<=$OneDirArrCnt; c++ )); do DirsArr[j++]="${DirsArr[k++]}"; done ;

        # Move work entry to what was current entry (swap)
        j=$CurrNdx
        k=0
        for (( c=1; c<=$OneDirArrCnt; c++ )); do DirsArr[j++]="${WorkArr[k++]}"; done ;

        CurrNdx=$LastNdx    # Step back one entry
        LastNdx=$(( $CurrNdx - $OneDirArrCnt ))

        if [[ $LastNdx -ge 0 ]]; then
            LastKey=$(echo "${DirsArr[$(( $LastNdx + 1 ))]}" | tr -dc '[:alnum:]/')
        else
            echo "+++++++++ Loop 3 Bumped: $Bump to top CurrNdx: $CurrNdx CurrKey: $CurrKey"
            echo "WorkArr: ${WorkArr[*]}"
            break
        fi
    done # CurrKey is now > LastKey, stop swapping

    TotBump=$(( $TotBump + $Bump))

    printf "  - END ---------------------- Loop 3:"
    echo " HoldNdx: $HoldNdx CurrNdx: $CurrNdx LastNdx: $LastNdx Bumped: $Bump"
    echo "   CurrKey: $CurrKey"
    echo "   LastKey: $LastKey"
    i=$HoldNdx
  done

  echo "Loop 2 bottom: i: $i HoldNdx: $HoldNdx CurrNdx: $CurrNdx LastNdx: $LastNdx"
  echo " CurrKey: $CurrKey"
  echo " LastKey: $LastKey"

  TotLoop=$(( $TotLoop + 1 ))
done

printf "* * * * * * * * *  Loop 1 bottom - Total Loops: $TotLoop"
echo " Bumps: $TotBump  * * * * * * * * *"

echo "${DirsArr[*]}"  > ~/.bafmanDirs   # "*" preserves separtator, "@" does not.

} ### BubbleDirsArr ()
```

Here are the final lines of program output:

```bash
= START ====================== Loop 3: HoldNdx: 24700 CurrNdx: 24700 LastNdx:   24690
 CurrKey: /home/rick/cache/yelp/WebKitCache/Version10/Blobs
 LastKey: /srv
  - END ---------------------- Loop 3: HoldNdx: 24700 CurrNdx: 5580 LastNdx: 5570 Bumped: 1912
   CurrKey: /home/rick/cache/yelp/WebKitCache/Version10/Blobs
   LastKey: /home/rick/cache/yelp/WebKitCache/Version10
Loop 2 bottom: i: 24710 HoldNdx: 24700 CurrNdx: 24700 LastNdx: 24700
 CurrKey: /srv
 LastKey: /srv
Loop 2 bottom: i: 24710 HoldNdx: 24700 CurrNdx: 24700 LastNdx: 24700
 CurrKey: /srv
 LastKey: /srv
* * * * * * * * *  Loop 1 bottom - Total Loops: 135 Bumps: 257158  * * * * * * * * *

real    29m27.445s
user    14m39.636s
sys 2m5.596s
```

Comment: There's no `~/.bafmanDirs` on my system. How would I use this?

Answer (score 2):

## Cut time from 1/2 hour in RAM to 9 seconds with disk

Bash arrays can be notoriously slow in many instances. You need to call the external sort program. Here is a code snippet:

```bash
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ExternalSortDirsArr () {

cp ~/.bafmanDirs ~/.bafmanDirs~ #Make backup copy
IFS="|" read -ra DirsArr < ~/.bafmanDirs
DirsArrCnt=${#DirsArr[@]}

DirPercent=0
DirLastPercent=0
DirCount=0
DirTotal=$(( $DirsArrCnt / $OneDirArrCnt ))
DirTotal=$(( $DirTotal + $DirTotal )) # Two passes

# Named FIFO pipes used between us and spawn-progress-log to avoid
# race conditions (flashing screen and keyboard lag) over 1/2 hour
YadNamedPipe="/tmp/bafman-yad-"$(date +%s) #seconds since EPOCH
mkfifo "$YadNamedPipe"
spawn-progress-log "$YadNamedPipe" \
    "bafman - Born Again File Manager" \
    "Four pass directory name external sort." &

# Create Keys Index
echo " "
echo "Create Keys-Index Pairs File"
> ~/.bafmanSort # Empty existing file.

time for (( i=0; i<$DirsArrCnt; i=i+$OneDirArrCnt )) ; do
    CurrKey=$(echo "${DirsArr[$(( $i + 1 ))]}" | tr -dc '[:alnum:]/')
    echo "$CurrKey|$i" >> ~/.bafmanSort

    # Update progress display
    DirPercent=$(( $DirCount * 100 / $DirTotal ))
    DirCount=$(( $DirCount + 1 ))
    if [[ "$DirPercent" -ne "$DirLastPercent" ]] ; then
        echo "#$CurrKey" > "$YadNamedPipe" & # Update YAD log window
        DirLastPercent=$DirPercent
        echo "$DirPercent" > "$YadNamedPipe" &         # Update YAD progress bar
    fi
done

# Call external sort program
echo " "
echo "Sort Keys-Index Pairs File"
time sort -k1 -t"|" ~/.bafmanSort -o ~/.bafmanSort

# Strip out keys
echo " "
echo "Strip out keys leaving Sorted Indices"
time cut -f2 -d '|' ~/.bafmanSort > ~/.bafmanNdx

echo " "
echo "Rewrite DirsArr by Sorted Index"
> ~/.bafmanDirs # Empty existing file.
> ~/.bafmanLog # Empty existing file.
Second=""
time while read -r line; do 
    j=$(( $line + $OneDirArrCnt ))
    for (( i=$line; i<j; i++ )); do
        echo -n "$Second""${DirsArr[i]}" >> ~/.bafmanDirs
        Second="|"

        # Update progress display
        DirPercent=$(( $DirCount * 100 / $DirTotal ))
        DirCount=$(( $DirCount + 1 ))
        if [[ "$DirPercent" -ne "$DirLastPercent" ]] ; then
#            echo "#$CurrKey" > "$YadNamedPipe" & # Update YAD log window
            DirLastPercent=$DirPercent
            echo "$DirPercent" > "$YadNamedPipe" &         # Update YAD progress bar
        fi
    done
done < ~/.bafmanNdx


echo " "
printf "* * * * * * * * *  ExternalSortDirsArr -- "
echo " Total DirsArr elements: $DirsArrCnt  Added: $DirsArrAddElementCount  * * * * * * * * *"

echo "100" > $YadNamedPipe &    # Signal close
rm -f $YadNamedPipe             # Remove FIFO named pipe for IPC

} ### ExternalSortDirsArr ()
```

Here are the benchmark time displays. Notice how 1/2 hour has dropped to 9 seconds:

```bash
Create Keys-Index Pairs File

real    0m3.899s
user    0m0.400s
sys 0m0.424s
 
Sort Keys-Index Pairs File

real    0m0.013s
user    0m0.012s
sys 0m0.000s
 
Strip out keys leaving Sorted Indices

real    0m0.001s
user    0m0.004s
sys 0m0.000s
 
Rewrite DirsArr by Sorted Index

real    0m1.407s
user    0m1.268s
sys 0m0.464s
 
* * * * * * * * *  ExternalSortDirsArr --  Total DirsArr elements: 24710  Added: 134  * * * * * * * * *
Gtk-Message: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.

real    0m9.667s
user    0m1.828s
sys 0m0.952s
```

Comment: Interpreted code using RAM is slower than compiled code using disk...  **;-) :P**